# Modrewrite - sometimes with query, sometimes without

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have an url that currently can look like this:

- http://domain.com/editProfile.php?id=1&programme=3
- http://domain.com/editProfile.php?id=1
- http://domain.com/editProfile.php

I am trying to make theese URLs look like this:

- http://domain.com/editprofile/1/3
- http://domain.com/editprofile/1
- http://domain.com/editprofile

Using this code:

`RewriteRule ^editprofile/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /editProfile.php?id=$1&programme=$2 [L]`

However, only the first one (1/3) works. When the query (programme or id) is removed, it doesn't.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is regex issue. Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^editprofile(?:/([^/]+)(?:/([^/]*))?)?/?$ /editProfile.php?id=$1&programme=$2 [L]
```